# System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog: Saving multiple file formats with same file extensions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

We want to save to files using .NET's *System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog*.

We have **multiple file formats** that use the **same file extension** (similar as in Excel where you also have two .CSV-formats (MS-DOS, and Macintosh)).

Does anyone know how we could get the exact file format the user selected and not only the file name with the file extension since they would be identical. Of course without having to re-implement the dialog... :-)

Cheers!

Comment: You'd have to open the file, inspect the contents, and find something that only exists in one of the two file formats.  Without knowing what the * actually* details of the file format are there's no way for us to tell you how to do that.

Comment: but how should I look into the file when I haven't saved it before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `FilterIndex`-Property of the `SaveFileDialog` to determinate which FileType the user has choosen.

```
SaveFileDialog oDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
oDialog.Filter = "CSV-File (Macintosh) (*.csv)|*.csv|CSV-File (MS-DOS) (*.csv)|*.csv";
oDialog.FilterIndex = 1;

if (oDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    switch (oDialog.FilterIndex)
    {
        case 1:
            // Handle CSV (Macintosh)
            break;
        case 2:
            // Handle CSV (MS-DOS)
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The file extensions are identical, according to the OP.

Comment: This is why you should use FilterIndex instead of the extensions. I've updated the answer, so that it should fit your question better. Excel does it the same way ;)